# For a region, is there always a $f$ which has no holomorphic extension to any larger region

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\Omega$ is a region, show that there always exists an holomorphic $f$ on $\Omega$ which has no holomophic extension to any larger region.

I think it has something to do with the natural boundary but I don't know how to start. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Show that there exists a sequence $a_n$ in $\Omega$ such that $a_n$ has no accumulation point in $\Omega$, but every boundary point of $\Omega$ is an accumulation point. Then use the Weierstraß product theorem.

Comment: Thank you. I have a few questions. By Weierstrass Theorem, do you mean Mittag-Leffler Theorem? The latter one is the one with prescribed poles. And how do you find the sequence $a_n$?

Comment: No, I mean Weierstraß product theorem. That one tells you that holomorphic functions with prescribed zeros exist (if the prescribed zeros have no accumulation point in $\Omega$, of course). So if such a function could be extended across any part of the boundary, it would vanish on a non-discrete set. To show the existence of a sequence with the desired properties, think lattice points, and shrink the lattice.

Comment: Oh yes. If $f$ has the prescribed poles, it wouldn't be holomorphic already. I got what you saying, thanks.